# Click event listener works just on the second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

This few lines of code suppose to work like a searching algorithm which also suggests keywords. Clicking on a keyword supposed to put the word into the input textbox. The words which can be results are the following: "first", "second".

The problem is that it doesn't work until the second click.

```js
var database = ["first", "second"];

var founded = true;

$( '#list' ).on( 'click', '.list_elem', function() {
  $("#box").val(this.textContent);
  $("#list").empty();
});

$("#box").on("change paste keyup", function() {
  $("#list").empty();
  var inputText = $(this).val();
  if (inputText.length != 0)
  {
      for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
          founded = true;
          for (var j = 0; j < inputText.length; j++) {
              if(!(database[i][j].toLowerCase() == inputText[j].toLowerCase()))
              {
                 founded = false;
              }
          }
          if(founded)
          {
              $( "#list" ).append('<div class="list_elem">' + database[i]  + '</div>');
          }
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box">
<div id="list"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the `<input>` looses focus and the change event is emitted, your code runs emptying the `#list` but then immediately after on `keyup` it repopulates it. You could use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event in place of `change` and `keyup` to workaround this:

```
$("#box").on("input paste", function() { ...
```

```js
var database = ["first", "second"];

var founded = true;

$('#list').on('click', '.list_elem', function() {
  $("#box").val(this.textContent);
  $("#list").empty();
});

$("#box").on("input paste", function() {
  $("#list").empty();
  var inputText = $(this).val();
  if (inputText.length != 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
      founded = true;
      for (var j = 0; j < inputText.length; j++) {
        if (!(database[i][j].toLowerCase() == inputText[j].toLowerCase())) {
          founded = false;
        }
      }
      if (founded) {
        $("#list").append('<div class="list_elem">' + database[i] + '</div>');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box">
<div id="list"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the input has focus when typing, the first click makes the input lose focus. The second click actually fires the onClick();
The easiest solution I can think of is removing focus when the mouse enters the list. [Here](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) is a link to jQuery's mouseenter() function.